# Nested Navigators efficient handling in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having nested navigators as below. I am **able to achieve the required output** ,but the problem is, for each screen i have to add a stack navigator, which seems inefficient.
How to handle it efficiently in React Navigation.

```
<DrawerNav>
  <BottomTabNav>
    <StackNav>
      <Screen1></Screen1>  //Navigation b/w these screens should have a back button
      <Screen2></Screen2>
    </StackNav>
    <StackNav></StackNav>
    <StackNav></StackNav>
    <StackNav></StackNav>
  </BottomTabNav>
  <StackNav></StackNav>  
  <StackNav></StackNav>
  <StackNav></StackNav>
</DrawerNav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create N screens inner DrawerNav or BottomTabNav without stackNavigator

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation

Comment: But, i won't get the back button for inner screens, which is required. Updated question for more clearity.

Comment: you can programe it yourself just put an icon and call const nav = useNavigation(); nav.back();